# Отличия в заголовках и их приемущества stdint-gcc.h и cstdint

Tags: c++, gcc

Хотелось бы узнать в чем разница данных подключений, и в чем особенность каждого из `stdint-gcc.h` и `cstdint`, т.к. оба представляют одни и те же типы. Но, я думаю при разработке под Linux лучше использовать все таки заголовочные файлы [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc), или я не прав.

Comment: Нет никакого `stdint-gcc.h`. Вы, похоже, залезли в детали реализации стандартной библиотеки в GCC, увидели там как-то сугубо внутренний файл и бросились его разглядывать. Этот файл не предназначен для ваших глаз. Это деталь реализации. Сегодня он есть, завтра - нет. Для вас есть только `<cstdint>`.